# I uploaded the image using SQL query in the blob format. can I use that to display the image Django template?

Tags: html, django, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQL workbench as a database and actually, I have not created any model, I uploaded the image using SQL query in the blob format. can I use that to display the image Django template?

main.html===>{{ para_image }} we are using to display the image

```
    <div class="parallax1" style="text-align:center ;  background-image: url('{{  para_image }}')">
      <p style="
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 20px;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;


     padding: 30px;  ">  {{ para_text|safe }} </p>


    </div>
```

views.py===(para_image) is the variable which holds the image

```
def main(request):
    try:
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM counts")

        myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
        mycursor1 = mydb.cursor()
        mycursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM parallax")

        myresult1 = mycursor.fetchall()


        mycursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM footer_content")

        myresult2 = mycursor.fetchall()

        mycursor3 = mydb.cursor()
        mycursor3.execute("SELECT * FROM about_us")

        myresult3 = mycursor.fetchall()
        print("##########00001111111100000##########")
        if(1):
            context={
                'students':myresult[0][2],
                'teachers':myresult[0][3],
                'workers': myresult[0][4],
                'para_text':myresult1[0][2],
                 """image"""
                'para_image':myresult1[0][1],
                'ftext':myresult2[0][1],
                'flink':myresult2[0][2],
                'tlink':myresult2[0][3],
                'ilink':myresult2[0][4],
                'about_us':myresult3[0][2]


            }
            return render(request, 'main.html', context)

        else:
            context={}
            return render(request, 'main.html', context)
    except:
        context = {}
        return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```

thank you

Comment: It's really not the Django way to use BLOB columns for images, since it's not efficient in the long run. It's also not the Django way to just create tables using MySQL workbench and query them by hand like you're doing. If you insist on doing that, though, you'd need to form a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) by base64-encoding the binary data.

Comment: Also, never use `try: except:`, especially like that. You'll have no chance to debug your code since it swallows all exceptions.